# Basing a 2nd Interface Builder XIB file on an existing one

Tags: xcode, ios, interface-builder, xib, nib

I need to create a few Views that are very similar - would it be a good/bad idea just to copy the existing .xib, and then modify the copy? i.e. would that cause circular references or more hassles than it's worth? If it is worth doing, is there a way to do from within XCode, or do you need to do from terminal/file manager? I am looking for a way to quickly generate very similar views without reconstructing from scratch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just instantiate multiple UIViewController instances using the same xib, and then make any changes you want to each instance.

```
UIViewController *firstView = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyXIB" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *secondView = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyXIB" bundle:nil];
```

etc...

You can also replace UIViewController with the name of a UIViewController subclass if needed.

Comment: Thanks - but I am wanting to be able to make changes to each instance in Interface Builder later?

Comment: You can just make several different XIB's in Xcode then copy & paste objects from one to another. Be sure to change any IBOutlet and IBAction connections accordingly.